# Problems trying to retrieve data from local storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

Im trying to retrieve some data from ionic local storage in this app made in IONIC and ANGULAR.
Still can't see what i'm ommitting but the data doesn't get exposed once the process is triggered.

Lets say i set the data in my ionic storage afeter having installed all the neccesary plugins in this way
:

```
DataStorageService

import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";

allMoviesfavorites: MovieSelectedDetails[] = [];

  saveAtStorage(movieToSave: MovieSelectedDetails) {
     ....asigning some value to variable allMoviesfavorites...

     this.storage.set("favorites", this.allMoviesfavorites);
  }
```

Also in the same service i establish the method to retrieve it in this way

```
DataStorageService

import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";

 allMoviesfavorites: MovieSelectedDetails[] = [];

constructor( private storage: Storage ) { this.loadfavoritesinStorage(); }
 
OPTION1
loadfavoritesinStorage() {
    this.storage.get("favorites").then((result) => {
      if (result == null) {
        result = [];
      }
      this.allMoviesfavorites = result;
      
    });

    return this.allMoviesfavorites;
  }

OPTION 2
 async loadfavoritesinStorage() {
    return this.storage.get("favorites").then((result) => {

       if (result == null) {
        result = [];
      }
      this.allMoviesfavorites =  result;
      console.log(result);
      

      return this.allMoviesfavorites;
    });
  }
```

As you see simply reach my local storage container of all the data i have been setting there, and once reached there whatever the result i got would be asigned to the variable allMoviesFavorite previously initialized as an empty array.

Then on the element i want to expose that data i trigger on the ngOnInit method a fucntion that calls the service and does the taks, asigning the data brought from service to the variable moviesInFavorite, that would be looped in the HTML to display graphically all data .
Also i log whatever the data is brought  in order to check, but i don't receive any data

```
Tab

import { DataStorageService } from "../services/data-storage.service";


moviesInFavorites: MovieSelectedDetails[] = [];
  constructor(private storageservice: DataStorageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFavorites();
  }

  async getFavorites() {
    let moviesInFavorites = await this.storageservice.loadfavoritesinStorage();
    console.log(moviesInFavorites);
    return (this.moviesInFavorites = moviesInFavorites);
  }
```

[image]
[image]

How could i improve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're returning `allMoviesfavorites` before the async code that loads the data from the storage is done.

This should work:

```
loadfavoritesinStorage() {
  return this.storage.get("favorites").then((result) => {
    if (result == null) {
      result = [];
    }

    this.allMoviesfavorites = result;
    
    return this.allMoviesfavorites; // <-- add the return here!      
  });
}
```

Comment: @EnriqueGF are you also returning the promise in the first line of the `loadfavoritesinStorage` method? Here: `return this.storage.get(...`

Comment: yes i did try just as you told me before, but keeps bringing the arrays empty

Comment: when i log the result it doesn't bring anything in its data

Comment: thus guess is more about referring to the ionic storage and its get method where the problem is

Comment: Could you please edit the post to include how you're setting the data in the storage?

Comment: referring to setting data on storage all goes fine ...cause data gets there....

Comment: I noticed this line in your code: `this.allMoviesfavorites =await  result;`. That's not correct... It should be `this.allMoviesfavorites = result;`.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this **[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64790924)** and see what's the difference with your code?

Comment: I don't know still how , but after restarting my pc, eventually worked.Thanks anyway for your suppor  @sebaferreras